# How to use one import in many files and classes in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, optimization, webpack, import

i have a problem, my bundle.js file after build is pretty big, i think it's beacuse im importing the same things in all my files, for example:
SomeComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar100 from '../Navbar/Navbar100';
import {Container, Row, Col, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from 'reactstrap';
import {NotificationContainer, NotificationManager} from 'react-notifications';
import 'react-notifications/lib/notifications.css';
import Footer from '../footer'

export default class InfoNav extends React.Component {
// some code
}
```

AnotherComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from 'reactstrap';
import {NotificationContainer, NotificationManager} from 'react-notifications';
import 'react-notifications/lib/notifications.css';

export default class User extends React.Component {
// some code
}
```

In these 2 files, im importing the same things from reactstrap, im also importing React from react, what is the best practice to do? My bundle.js file after build is 1,3mb now, it's pretty high

Comment: you can write many smaller components in one in one file.That may not be the right solution:P

Comment: read more about lazy imports and code splitting

Comment: i can't find a way, anyone can help?